# Full screen in multiple windows in single screen

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have 65 inch tv which I use as monitor for windows.

I want to open multiple windows and each windows must have full screen , which I use for Stock market trading charts.I can hide address bar and bookmark etc , but can I do full screen of 4 windows in single screen ?

It can be in firefox , chrome , IE or any browser.

Answer (score 0):

In a single screen, to get multiple windows, you must use Windowed mode (full screen will not work). Set up your applications and then size them to fit your screen and with each other

If you have Windows 10 you can use Snap to Edge, Snap to Half screen and Snap to Quadrant.  That may help you, but I think Windowed mode is better.

https://www.howtogeek.com/198230/how-to-use-snap-assist-and-2x2-snap-on-windows-10/